# msgpack-python Unable to allocate internal buffer

Tags: python, django, serialization, uwsgi, msgpack

I used msgpack-python 0.1.12 in a uwsgi server with python2.7.2 .

After running for some time， the server will throw a lot of exceptions as follows:

File "_msgpack.pyx", line 171, in msgpack._msgpack.packb (msgpack/_msgpack.c:2356)

File "_msgpack.pyx", line 58, in msgpack._msgpack.Packer.**cinit** (msgpack/_msgpack.c:803)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate internal buffer.

Any help will be appreciated.